# Async/Await socket receiving data issue

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, async-await, task

Is this is a good approach to read data from `Socket`?

```
public class StateObject : IDisposable
{
    private const int _bufferSize = 1024;
    public byte[] Buffer { get; } = new byte[_bufferSize];
    public int BufferSize { get; } = _bufferSize;
    public MemoryStream MsStream { get; }

    public EnhStateObject()
    {
        MsStream = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MsStream.Dispose();
    }
}

public async static Task<int> ReceiveAsync(this Socket client, StateObject state)
{
    var task = await await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
    (cb, s) => client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, cb, s),
    client.EndReceive, null).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        state.MsStream.Write(state.Buffer, 0, t.Result);
        return t;
    });

    if (task == state.BufferSize) await client.ReceiveAsync(state);

    return task;
}
```

I mean, transfer outside the object and storing the received information in it through the recursive call.

Or is there a more elegant way to do this using the same `FromAsync` wrapper?

Comment: If this works, then it may be a better fit for Code Review than SO. May need to add more details either way though (e.g. the definition of `StateObject` would probably help). `await await` looks suspicious.

Comment: I've updated the post. About `StateObject` nothing special. `await await` [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Comment: agree, it can be easier: remove one `await` befor `Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync` and return from `ContinueWith` `t.Result`

Comment: `TcpClient` is a good choise for clientside. My clientside runs on `.net4`, (instead of serverside, witch runs on `.net4.6.1`) and there is no way to use `ReadAsync`, AFAIK. As a result, I would like to write code that can be used on both platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a good way of reading data from a socket. You are reinventing the wheel here; [use `NetworkStream` instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8fz0y3(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't know why you need to use the low-level `Socket` API, but, well, you don't.

Instead, wrap your `Socket` in a `NetworkStream` at the callsite, like so:

```
Socket socket = ....;
Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
```

Then you can just read data using `ReadAsync()` as you would expect (bonus points: no state object to pass around and you can mock the stream with a standard `MemoryStream` in tests)

```
var buffer = new byte[1024];
var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

If you're using Tcp, I'd recommend using [the TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) API instead of working directly with sockets.

Comment: Thnxs, that is good for my serverside with `.net4.6.1`. What about a clientside with `.net4`? How to make APM and not to sink to the level of `Sockets` API there?

Comment: It's a good idea for you to mention your requirements in your question, which includes the .NET framework you're using. .NET 4 does not have `ReadAsync`, but it does still have `NetworkStream`.  Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way to use asynchronous reads on this stream in that version without using the old `BeginRead`/`EndRead` methods

Comment: Sorry for requirements, I'll teke it in future.